# Github Pages. Link empty and Error: Failed to load module script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, github-pages

I'm trying to upload a project on Github Pages but when I visit the link I get a white page with nothing and the following error in the console:

Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/jsx". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

It refers to the main.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
<React.StrictMode>
<App />
</React.StrictMode>
)
```

Any idea what could be going on?

Comment: Not really. We would need to see more code. Like package.json and steps to deploy. Have you tried following this guide: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#github-pages

Comment: Thanks for that, that guide was very helpfull. Now I have another problem. I can't update changes in my repo after deploying it.

Comment: You can't update changes? Do you have a specific error?

Answer (score 0):

It`s showing up because you open the react app with the live server.
Instead you should run it with npm.

Open the terminal and run:

```bash
$ npm run dev
```

And click on the link that it`s providing you.
Whenever you wanna open the app you have to do this step.
it works just like a live server but actually, it hosts your app on a local host.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you having the same problem tha I had, I did all the config that was necessary by github, but I forget to build de main project.
Build the main project, by runing the command, specifically in the same level of package.json file::

```
npm run build
```

After that you'll hava a folder called dist, this was the solve for my problem, my project use Vite.

You can also check this link that a used to solve my problem: https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html

Best regards man.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're experiencing is a common issue when trying to serve JSX files directly without compiling them into standard JavaScript, which browsers can understand. GitHub Pages serves static files and does not compile JSX to JavaScript. Here's how you can resolve this issue:

**Build Your Project**

Your React project must be compiled into plain JavaScript before it can be deployed. If you're using Create React App, you can build your project using the following command

```
npm run build
```

Answer (score -1):

My friend, if you are using react, you MUST open your console and write
"npm run dev"

NOTE: That command will vary deppending on your current instalation of react you can check what is your current starting command by reviewing your package.json file.
[This is my example, since I'm using vite I must write npm run dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB69C.jpg)

If you try to open your html with live server like a regular HTML file, you browser will display that error.

Good look my brother.